# Sed working with two lines

Tags: sed

I would like to create a sed command that takes
every two lines in a document

and
if the first line ends with [letter or number]
and the second line contains dot (.)
it will join these two lines together.

Is it possible with `sed`?

Comment: When asking this type of question, please make sure to include example input and output so we can understand what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Much better if you show example input and desired output but in first close:

```
sed ':1;N;/\w\n/{s/\n\([^\n]*\.\)/ \1/;t1};P;D'
```